# Two-way DataBinding went wrong after device rotation

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-architecture-components, androidx, two-way-binding

I use **Android DataBinding Library (Two-way)** with **LiveData** *(binding syntax @={})*

To reuse UI, I intensively use **include layout** mechanism when designing layout file.
Actually, I include **a same layout file multiple times** in building a form layout.

Everything gone well until the DEVICE ROTATION. After the device rotates, ***all the field (editText) get the same value as in the last row*** (as shown in the picture below).

The problem happens when the activity is re-created after the rotation so I can prevent this by setting for android:configChanges of the activity. 
But I'm curious about the **root of this problem** and **how to solve its.**.

You can find the major parts of the source code  below or [full source code](https://github.com/hahv/Android_TwoWayBindingLiveData).
Thanks in advance.

[image]

---

SOURCE CODE

- **Layout for a row (1 TextView & 1 EditText)**

[image]

- **Reuse the layout above 2 time in main layout**
  [image]
- **ViewModel**
  [image]
- **Main activity - Binding in OnCreate**
  [image]

Comment: You just need to remove this line `binding.setLifecycleOwner(this);`

Comment: Did you get any chance to look at the answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To one who may concern about this problem, the reason seems to be related to the ID of editText in form row layout (Layout for a row (1 TextView & 1 EditText)), i.e.             android:id="@+id/editTextID" in this case.

Three rows for first name, last name and password created by using the same row layout so editTexts for these fields haves the same ids.

After the rotation, the frameworks could notify the changes in edit text of the last row (password) but the two first rows also receive these updates. That probably causes the problem.

To resolve it, *simple remove android:id="@+id/editTextID" in the row layout.*
There is nothing related to ViewModel or its lifeCycle.

Comment: Hi, if you remove the id for this view, how to find it if you need to access other properties ? Is there another way to solve this ? thank you

Comment: Try findviewwithtag!

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove this line `binding.setLifecycleOwner(this);`. I did verify myself.

Comment: oh no, to make LiveData works, it should bound to a lifeCycleOwner.

Answer (score -2):

add this line to your activity in manifest file,

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

Comment: When you rotate the device your activity gets recreated so all the resources are allocated new memory and references so thats why data binding is not working.

Comment: you can solve this by multiple ways,

1. preventing the activity to recreate as of above
2. use savedInstance to save your state of the app and set it again after activity is created
3. you can also use lifecycler observer component to solve this

Comment: Actually the databinding framework retain the ViewModel so the viewModel before and after the rotation is the same (checked). But weird thing happen as shown in the question. What do u mean by solution 3 (how)

Comment: @HardikChauhan take a look more about `ViewModel` https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel

Comment: yeah i know viewmodel can survive the onconfigurationchange.

Comment: Declaring `configChanges` attribute in manifest mean we manually handling the configuration changes this is not a good answer for this question